# Value interpolation in 2d from scattered data

Tags: c++, interpolation

I'm looking for a way to interpolate values from some 2D scattered data. I have a 3d points that represent a terrain from which I want to interpolate intermediate points. For input (X,Y) coordinates I need Z (height) value.

[This article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation#Irregular_grid_.28scattered_data.29) may also help you understand my wishes. There is a library in matlab called **triscateredinterp** that I think it does what I want.

What is a lightweight way to accomplish this interpolation in C++?

Comment: is your data altitude on a 2D inputs?  is it on a regular grid, or scattered?

Comment: I have scattered 3D points. My data is altitude.

Comment: and you want to give a **2D** value and interpolate the altitude?

Comment: You don't need 3D interpolation then, just 2D.  I could explain the math behind, but fear being down-voted for it not being a very C++ answer.

Comment: I edited the question to remove the explicit request for a link to a library. I believe it is on-topic now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need 3D interpolation (triscateredinterp).  You have data based on 2D inputs; the 3rd dimension is your output.  If I understand correctly you want to provide a point in 2D (something between the original points, and interpolate the value.

Light weight?  nearest neighbor!; then bi-linear interpolation; then bi-cubic (and others).  The first is simple, the others require an increasing amount of math.

Bi-linear: For each point to be interpolated, find the nearest 3 points to your X and Y:

```
lat long Altitude
X1   Y1   A1
X2   Y2   A2
X3   Y3   A3
```

Make these matrices:

```
    X1   Y1   1                      A1
X = X2   Y2   1                  Y = A2
    X3   Y3   1                      A3
```

B is the interpolation coefficients we will calculate for those three nearest points (and can be re-used for all points in the area)

```
    B1
B = B2
    B3
```

The matrix equation is: `X*B = Y`

You could use brut force:
Multiply both sides by XT:  `XT*X*B = XT*Y`
Take the inverse of XT*X:  `B = (XT*X)^-1 *XT*Y`.

Yes 3x3 matrix inversion.  Tying this back to a C++ question, you might use Boost for your matrix operations.

Here is another similar C++ question: [Solving a system of equations programmably?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276341/solving-a-system-of-equations-programmably)

One problem that can arise from the bi-linear technique is that as your interpolated point becomes closer to a different set of 3 values you can get some jumps (how would you interpolate 4 points in a saddle configuration?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm familiar with matrix multiplication and c++ :) I'm a bit confused here. What to do with vector B when it's calculated?. _How do you use coordinates of point to be interpolated to get new value?_

Is your solution something like fitting a plane on nearest 3 points and then intersecting with vertical line where intersection is the value we seek?

Comment: B is the solution, the coeficients in the formula that will work for any X and Y to find A.   A = X*B1 + Y*B2 + B3.  It is the formula for the plane that intersects your original 3 points.

Comment: As you mention, this solution is not continuous, so I am not sure what good it can be for scattered points.  Replacing the 3 nearest points, by the 3 vertices of the triangle that contains the point, assuming you have a (e.g. Delaunay) triangulation of the points, then you can do continuous interpolation, and this opens more options.

Answer (score 1):

One good method for scattered points is Natural Neighbor Interpolation.
You can check the implementation available in CGAL for example : http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Interpolation/index.html

Comment: Links are not answers. Answers on SO are expected to be self-contained. Please [review this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/135887)  and add enough detail to your answer to make it not completely reliant on an external link.

Comment: Well, I would not mind giving more details, but I don't think that this is what the question was about.  Actually, my answer was not so much the link, but rather the words "Natural Neighbor Interpolation".  Moreover, the actual question is about finding a C++ library that provides the functionality, for which my link is an exact answer.

Comment: Sigh, I need to remember to read the question when doing reviews.  Library recommendations are off-topic on SO, and I've voted to close the question.  It'd be helpful if you could at least provide some sample code on how using this library would solve the problem.

Comment: Well, the sample code can be found by clicking the link...